# change the normal button to press and hold button jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two buttons in my code, one of them open the burger menu and the second one changes the size of the div, I want to change only the second button into a hold button that works after 3 seconds delay.

- code:

```
$document.on("click", ".navbar-toggle-overlay", function() {
            var a = $(this)
              , d = $(".overlay-menu");
            d.is(":visible") ? (a.removeClass("active"),
            d.fadeOut(),
            c(),
            $(".nav-container .image, .view-toggle").removeClass("white"),
            $(".project").removeClass("hidden")) : (a.addClass("active"),
            d.fadeIn(),
            b(),
            $(".project").addClass("hidden"),
            $(".nav-container .image, .view-toggle").addClass("white"))
        })
```

- html:

```
<div class="burger-container">
<button class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-overlay burger" type="button">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
</button>
button class="view-toggle">
<span class="slider-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```js
// Attach an event listener to the mousedownevent of the button
$('button').on('mousedown', function() {
    let btn$ = $(this);
  
  
  // Attach an event listener to the document, on mouseup, to cancel the delayed action
  // Also add a namespace ('.myBtn') to be able to remove this event later
  $(document).on('mouseup.myBtn', () => {
    // Further down we add the delayed function that runs if the button is pressed for 3s,
    // here we clear it, if the button wasn't pressed long enough
    clearTimeout( $(this).data('delayedFn') );
    // undbind this event listener after it was triggered
    $(document).unbind('mouseup.myBtn');
  });
  
  // Store the delayed funtion somehow, here we do it in the buttons data
  btn$.data('delayedFn', setTimeout(() => {     
      // Do whatever you want to be done after the delay
        $('div').addClass('red');
      // don't forget to unbind the listener for the mouseup event
      $(document).unbind('mouseup.myBtn');
  }, 3000));
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: darkgrey;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Hold for 3s
</button>
<br><br>
<div></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem is that I want to change exactly that code and add a setTimeout to it instead of adding a new code, do you think I can do this?

Comment: I dont get what you mean. Of course you will need to add 'new code'. Just attach the shown code to your button.

Comment: I mean, when I attach the code  to the main code, these changes will work on all buttons because almost all of them have common classes, but I only want to change this one button. sorry I'm almost new to jquery if I am wrong something, please correct me. warm regards.

Comment: The `$('button')`-selector in my code needs to be changed to the selector of the button you want to attach that functionality to. If that happens to be a button that is currently only selectable by a class that spreads the event listener to other buttons, you need to be more specific with your selector. You can either introduce another class or an id and add that to the button or select it by its parents to make the selection unique.

Comment: thank you very much, it was done correctly

Comment: Vielen Dank  ; )